# columns in expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, multiple-columns

I have used this tutorial to do the expandable list view. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/.
But i want to make a small change as shown in the below image. I dnt know to implement the items underlined in red. Is it possible to have columns in the expandable list view?

.xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

can any one help me with this. any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's really the same thing as customizing a `ListView` row. Set up a custom layout and use the `ViewHolder` pattern: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: I have edited my question n posted the .xml file. can u tell me how to add textview in that. it crashed when i did

Comment: I see you like androidhive. So, among the billions of results of a 5 secs search, here's a androidhive tutorial link: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: haha.. let me try this

Comment: Beware... It's for ListView, not ExpandableListView, so you must adapt it to your needs. But, after all, an ExpandableListView is like a ListView which holds a ListView for each of its items...

Comment: @Der Golem yup i got it

Answer (score 1):

You need two layouts: expandable header and child items. In your example they are `list_item` and `group_item`.

Edit them and add the rest of fields.

If you use weights for fields widths, you can make header and rows to to look as a grid.

Briefly:
For header (`group_layout`) use a LinearLayout containing four TextViews (start with weights 2, 1, 1, 1 and adapt it according with tests).

For row (`list_item`) use a RelativeLayout containing:

- LinearLayout exactly as the one in group layout (four TextViews with same weights as you set there) aligned to Top.
- Two TextViews (toppings) aligned to left. Set property `below` accordingly.
- The other two ImageViews. Align them accordingly as well (right and one next to the other)

Have a look into RelativeLayout parameters to set your views.